# how to find the position of a string in a file in unix shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

Can you please help me solve this puzzle?  I am trying to print the location of a string (i.e., line #) in a file, first to the std output, and then capture that value in a variable to be used later.  The string is “my string”, the file name is “myFile” which is defined as follows:

```
this is first line
this is second line
this is my string on the third line
this is fourth line
the end
```

Now, when I use this command directly at the command prompt:

```
% awk ‘s=index($0, “my string”) { print “line=” NR, “position= ” s}’ myFile
```

I get exactly the result I want:

```
% line= 3, position= 9
```

My question is:  if I define a variable VAR=”my string”, why can’t I get the same result when I do this:

```
% awk ‘s=index($0, $VAR) { print “line=” NR, “position= ” s}’ myFile
```

It just won’t work!!  I even tried putting the $VAR in quotation marks, to no avail?  I tried using VAR (without the $ sign), no luck.  I tried everything I could possibly think of ... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` variables are not the same as shell variables.  You need to define them with the `-v` flag

For example:

```
$ awk -v var="..." '$0~var{print NR}' file
```

will print the line number(s) of pattern matches.  Or for your case with the index

```
$ awk -v var="$Var" 'p=index($0,var){print NR,p}' file
```

using all uppercase may not be good convention since you may accidentally overwrite other variables.

to capture the output into a shell variable

```
$ info=$(awk ...)
```

for multi line output assignment to shell array, you can do

```
$ values=( $(awk ...) ); echo ${values[0]}
```

however, if the output contains more than one field, it will be assigned it's own array index.  You can change it with setting the `IFS` variable, such as

```
$ IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b"); values=( $(awk ...) )
```

which will capture the complete lines as the array values.

Comment: Brilliant! It worked ... Thanks so much, karakfa!  :-)  How can I 'capture' the result in a variable?

Comment: worked, thanks!  now, last question, i promise.  suppose i have i have multiple strings i'm dealing with, in my example, let's say i have the awk command in a loop to find all occurrences of the the string "this is".  the values returned for the positions, how can i store them in an array or a list?  i.e., i want to keep them?  -thx.

Comment: you don't need a loop for all instances of the same string, awk will return all matches.  see the update for array assignment with a caveat.

Comment: @lookiluke If you think it answers your question and will be useful for others please accept it as the answer.